# Migration didn't migrate all comments

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, migration, migrated-questions

I migrated a question from [one site](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/68466/755) to [another site](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/37398/5038).  3 of the 4 comments got copied over, but the 4th didn't get copied.  Why not?  Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments that include a link to (or, in this case, just the domain) of the destination site in a migration don't get moved on the assumption that there's little value in them outside of pointing to that site.

In most cases, this works out fine since these comments tend to be along the lines of "This is off-topic here and belongs on $site". In this case, it doesn't really work... but there's unfortunately not much we can do about it at this point.